# MySQL Update Incorrectly Updating Multiple Rows (failed "fixes" shown)

Tags: mysql, pdo

My script attempts to update DB values WHERE $system_id has a certain value; the problem is that it is updating DB values even WHERE $system_id has the wrong value.

More specifically: $g1choice, $g2choice, and $g3choice are being updated for any row in which $factor matches, regardless of $system_id

What am I doing wrong? Thanks! :)

Below: 1) code; 2) failed attempts to fix code

```
 //Insert & Update Factor A table
    $page_query = $pdo->query(
        "SELECT sum(task_1) AS task01, sum(task_2) AS task02, sum(task_3) AS task03, rand01
        FROM pages
        GROUP BY rand01"
    );

    while ($row = $page_query->fetch()) {

        $factors = $pdo->prepare(
            "SELECT factor
            FROM factorA
            WHERE factor = ? && system_id = ?"
        );
        $factors->execute([$row['rand01'], $system_id]);

        $count = count($factors->fetchAll());

        if ($count > 0) {
            $pdo->prepare(
                "UPDATE factorA
                SET g1choice = ?, g2choice = ?, g3choice = ?
                WHERE factor = ?"
                /* failed fix: WHERE factor = ? &&  system_id = ?" */  
            )->execute([$row['task01'], $row['task02'], $row['task03'], $row['rand01']]);
                /* failed fix:   )->execute([$row['task01'], $row['task02'], $row['task03'], $row['rand01'],$system_id]); */     
        } else {
            $pdo->prepare(
                "INSERT INTO factorA (system_id, factor, g1choice, g2choice, g3choice)
                VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)"
            )->execute([$system_id, $row['rand01'], $row['task01'], $row['task02'], $row['task03']]);
        }
    }

  /*failed fixes below*/

    //failed fix (1):

     failed fix:
     $page_query = $pdo->prepare(
        "SELECT sum(task_1) AS task01, 
         sum(task_2) AS task02, sum(task_3)       
         AS task03, rand01
        FROM pages 
        WHERE system_id= ?
        GROUP BY rand01"
    );
    $factors->execute([$system_id]);        
            */

  //failed fix (2)
/*
               if ($count > 0) {
            $pdo->prepare(
                "UPDATE factorA
                SET g1choice = ?, g2choice = ?, g3choice = ?    

                was WHERE factor = ?"
/* failed fix: WHERE factor = ? &&  system_id = ?" */             

           )->execute([$row['task01'], $row['task02'], $row['task03'], $row['rand01']]);
    /* failed fix:   )->execute([$row['task01'], $row['task02'], $row['task03'], $row['rand01'],$system_id]); */

    */
```

Comment: Your update query is not actually filtering on `system_id`, only `factor`.

Comment: Thanks-- I tried WHERE factor = ? &&  system_id = ? (as mentioned in the "failed fixes" section), but seem not to have gotten it right. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice those. Are those failed fixes copied correctly? The `]` after `$system_id` in both places looks out of place.

Comment: Thanks. > The ] after $system_id in both places looks out of place.< I think execute statements, even those with only a single variable, always go inside "([" and "])". I could be wrong about that, though.

Comment: Ah, yeah, I didn't notice the leading opening bracket, and thought it might be an accidental holdover from the $row[] entries. Which version of php? according to the docs, `[`, `]` syntax was not introduced until 5.4; and none of the official `execute` examples use the `[]` notation.

Comment: >[, ] syntax was not introduced until 5.4< Good point; I'm actually uncertain of the version being used, and the version on my server.... Thanks.